# Zoom H1n record external and internal mono at same time?

Tags: zoom

I want to use the Zoom H1n to record my voice and an instrument at the same time.

According to [this video by Zoom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44v8EGGW_HA), "using a TS plug [on the line in] will result in a mono signal which will only appear on the left channel."

I think it should be feasible to use the unused right channel & its associated DAC to record mono from the built-in y mic. **(How) can I do this?** I'm down to mod my device if need be.

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/XqZIObj58vw) details a similarly minded solution to record two external mono mics, but does not seem to allow picking and choosing internal mics.

Comment: It isn't feasible - Zoom do not provide the hardware to do this.